# Spring - register Beans before everything else

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to register a series of `BeanDefinition`(s) before every other Bean gets created. That's because those registered Bean(s) are needed for autowiring and `ApplicationContext#getBean` calls.

I cannot use `@DependsOn`, obviously.

Example:

```
final var beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
beanDefinition.setBeanClass(...);
beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);
beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);
beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
beanDefinition.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE);

registry.registerBeanDefinition("...", beanDefinition);
```

Which point/interface/lister can I use to obtain this? Keep in mind I need an instance of `BeanDefinitionRegistry`.

**Adding explanation as required.**

Those definitions are created from a list of Classes gathered by scanning the classpath. Those classes are not Spring Bean(s) natively, so I need to integrate them into my `ApplicationContext`. Those classes, however, accepts constructor arguments which are Spring Beans.
That's why I'm setting

```
beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);
beanDefinition.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
```

Those new registered Beans are there used by other Bean(s) (native Beans).

Comment: Why not just create an `@Bean` method... Spring will figure out the rest...

Comment: @M.Deinum those `BeanDefinition`(s) are dynamic.

Comment: Then please add a bit more desciption/context to your question as that appears to be lacking. Also explain what is dynamic about it.

Comment: @M.Deinum done!

Comment: maybe use _@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)_ on the component where you create your dynamical beans.

Comment: Do those classes have a single constructor? Which Spring version are you using. If there is a single constructor, and are using Spring 4.3 or later you can just register them as beans by simply component scanning.

Comment: @M.Deinum there is a single constructor, however i cannot annotate them as `@Component`. I'm on Spring 5.1.*

Comment: You don't have to annotate classes with `@Component` to have them detected. You can create your own filter which detects them. `@Component` is just one of the ways. You can also use an aspectJ or regexp to detect components without the need to add `@Component` to them.

Comment: @M.Deinum really? Could you point me to the documentation?

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.Filter.html. The `@ComponentScan` has an `includeFilter` argument which you can use to define a filter to detect components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make the solution too complex. If your only goal is to have non `@Component` annotated classes be detected by component scanning and have them used as Spring Beans simply define a custom `includeFilter` for the `@COmponentScan`.

You can use a filter of type `ASPECTJ` or `REGEX` to match a package or type.

```
@ComponentScan(includeFilter = @Filter(type=REGEX, expression="com.foo.bar.*))
```

Something like that will automatically detect your beans (assuming they are in a packaged being scanned) and create spring beans out of them. If they have a single constructor that will automatically be used to create an instance.

Comment: The regex solution seems fine! In more "complex" scenarios maybe the solution posted by Karol is fine?

Comment: If you need to revert to that you might better take a step back and reconsider. Those aren't generally needed and generally only for library/framework developers.

Comment: Infact those classes comes from external JAR(s), which might be added by "clients". But must be agnostic to Spring

Comment: Btw, those scanned components can be registered as Prototype?

Comment: They will receive the default scope of `singleton` if they need to be something else you would, indeed, need a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`, do the scanning yourself and process the read definitions. But that is everything you would need to do, as everything else (constructor detection etc) is still done automatically. You could use a custom `ScopeResolver` to create beans from earlier packages into prototype beans.

Comment: "do the scanning yourself" means doing what I'm doing now, scanning the classpath manually and for each class found create a definition, right?

Comment: No... Use the spring `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` which does all that for you. Although you might first want to check if you can make it work with a custom `ScopeMetaDataResolver` the default only looks at the `@Scope` annotation, but you could extend it to take your packages into consideration.

Comment: Oh, those are all new things for me. And how would I make Spring use my custom `ScopeMetaDataResolver`? Sorry if that seems a stupid question but I have no clue.

Comment: You pass the classname to the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Register a new [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) or [`BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) bean in your context. This bean will get invoked after bean definitions are scanned but before actual beans are constructed:

> Extension to the standard BeanFactoryPostProcessor SPI, allowing for the registration of further bean definitions before regular BeanFactoryPostProcessor detection kicks in. In particular, BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor may register further bean definitions which in turn define BeanFactoryPostProcessor instances.

Comment: Thanks Karol! Gonna try the custom filter solution posted above first, and use this one for more complex scenarios. Btw, how would you compare `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` with those two classes you mentioned?

Comment: `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` isn't usable as that requires an annotation. That is used fo the `@Enable*` annotations.